# SSRS report - export to Excel not using custom code properly

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ssrs-2012

I am having a problem exporting a report into Excel. The report is using some custom code that works fine for PDF and Word, but in Excel it is not working properly. Here is the code.

Textbox expression:

```
=Code.MakeProjectstHyperLinks(LookupSet(Fields!PointName.Value, Fields!PointName.Value, 
Fields!ProjectName.Value, "SystemPointDetails"), LookupSet(Fields!PointName.Value, 
Fields!PointName.Value, Fields!ProjectId.Value, "SystemPointDetails"))
```

Custom code:

```
Function MakeProjectstHyperLinks(ByVal ProjectNames As Object(), ByVal ProjectIds As Object()) 
    As String  
    If ProjectNames Is Nothing Then  
        Return Nothing  
    End If  

    Dim builder As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()  
    builder.Append("<ul>")  

    For number As Integer  = 0 To ProjectNames.Length - 1
      builder.Append("<li>")
      builder.append("<a href=""" & Report.Parameters!Trending_URL.Value & "?projectid=" & 
      ProjectIds(number)  & """ target=""_blank"">" & ProjectNames(number) & "</a>")
      builder.append("</li>")  
    Next  
    builder.Append("</ul>")  

    Return builder.ToString()  
End Function
```

What happens in Excel is that in this line:

```
builder.append("<a href=""" & Report.Parameters!Trending_URL.Value & "?projectid=" & 
      ProjectIds(number)  & """ target=""_blank"">" & ProjectNames(number) & "</a>")
```

ProjectIds(number) always show the first element of ProjectIds although "number" is correct. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check _(and correct)_ your tags. To me this looks like VB.NET, not VB6.

Comment: Nope, it is old good VB.

Comment: Are you sure that [System.Text.Stringbuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) is a VBA/VB6 object?

Comment: This is from Google: You can extent basic SSRS capabilities by using custom code. This code is Visual Basic. Also, the expression language used in SSRS is Visual Basic. But I see your point. Seems like we also can use some .net objects. I will add another tag. But the problem I am having most likely has someting to do with the hyperlinks getting exportrd into Excel.

Comment: Agree with @HelO'Ween. There are numerous clues that the code you show isn't VB6 or VBA, so that tag isn't applicable

Comment: The parens on subroutine calls without `call` is another giveaway that this is not VBA or VB6

Comment: Let's consult the actual [SSRS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) of MS, where they state that _"Embed code written in Visual Basic directly in your report. If your code refers to a Microsoft .NET Framework that is not Math or Convert, you must add the reference to the report."_ Referencing .NET Framework is a clear giveaway that VB.NET is meant with this. When MS speaks of _"Visual Basic"_ nowadays, they refer to VB.NET, as VB6 is considered to be dead and gone.